# Confused about the proper way of testing for an improvement or worsening

Tags: r, wilcoxon-signed-rank, sign-test

I want to check if a new equipment improves a score compared with the older equipment. My database contains the score with the old equipment, and the scores with each new equipment. I googled, userR'd, checked similar journal articles and saw that [one of them used the sign test to assess the improvement in the grading](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/anae.12075/full).

## EDIT

To make it clear, [the journal article which studied a very similar question used the sign test](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/anae.12075/full). They and I have data like this one:

```
               New equipment
Old equipment  1  2  3
            1 33  0  0
            2 37  8  1
            3 12  4  0
            4  2  0  0
```

This table should be read like this:

- Numbers 1-4 are scores for some condition (1 is better, 4 is worst).
- The first row starting with 1 means that the old equipment provided a score of 1 in 33 patients, and the situation did not change with the new equipment.
- The second row starting with 2 means that the old equipment provided a score of 2 in 46 patients (derived from 37+8+1). The new equipment provided a score of 3 in 1 patient, a score of 2 in 8 patients, and a score of 1 in 37 patients. This is a good improvement, but in ~2% of cases, things may get worse.
- The third row starting with 3 means that the old equipment provided a score of 3 in 16 patients (derived from 12+4). The new equipment provided a score of 2 in 4 patients, and a score of 1 in 12 patients. This is a major improvement.
- The fourth row starting with 4 means that the old equipment provided a score of 4 in 2 patients. The new equipment provided a score of 1 in both of these patients. This is a major improvement. However, only 2 out of 97 patients scored 4 with no instrument. Therefore we may conclude that only patients who score high (3 or 4) with no instrument may benefit from using an instrument.

**I think that the best option is to test each row separately with wilcoxon test, by comparing the medians of both conditions (old equipment and new equipment).** As an example:

```
score.2 <- subset(original.df, old-equipment %in% 2)
wilcox.test(score.2$old-equipment, score.2$new-equipment, alternative="great")
```

and repeat this for each score with the old equipment.
I couldn't see a way to use the sign test for this. What is your suggestion to test this condition properly?

## EDIT#2

I think the Wilcoxon signed rank test is appropriate to compare the differences of two new methods/instruments over a common old method/instrument. But when it comes to test the significance of the difference of one method over the other, it has a shortcoming. Let me explain with an example:

Lets say, on 4 trials, I could eat 3,4,4,5 peas with a fork. With a spoon, I could eat 4,5,5,6 peas. Since the median of the spoon-trial is higher than the median of the fork-trial, we can conclude that spoon is better for eating peas. It won't differ if the spoon-trial ends up as 6,5,5,4 or 5,5,5,5 or even 1,1,10,10. The spoon-median is higher than the fork-median and the Wilcoxon test will yield a low p-value. But when it comes to grading or notes, or anything that requires consistency, it differs. In my case, I'm working with old and new scoring systems. When a new method/instrument consistently achieves higher scores compared with the old one, it is simply better than the old one. But when it achieves very good scores in half of the trials, and very bad scores in the other half (but still better sum or median than the old one), it is not better. It may score better in some circumstances but it is not reliable. That is the weakness of the Wilcoxon test. It does not take the paired nature of the data into account.

So my exact question is, how can I make the Wilcoxon test see this problem from a "paired samples" aspect. So I have data, where I test each subject with three different instruments and would like to know if it is worth the effort to switch to any of the new instruments.

```
#dput
structure(list(Mallampati = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), VL = c(1, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), DL = c(1, 
1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2)), .Names = c("Mallampati", 
"VL", "DL"), row.names = c(NA, 40L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The sign test code you linked to is intended to work on raw data. It's not clear to me why they didn't just use `binom.test`; the code could be a one-liner then.

Comment: I agree. But I wonder if the sign test is really appropriate in this situation. I removed the abstract example and put the real results to clarify things. Could you very mind to check if my solution is appropriate or not?

Comment: The Wilcoxon signed-rank test seems appropriate to me.  Pair patients up and calculate the difference (old minus new for example) and test for a difference in median.  I'm not sure what you mean by reapeating this for each score with the old equipment...I would just lump all the patients together with the associated difference of old minus new.

Comment: Since there are two new instruments, your suggestion is ok for comparing the difference of new instruments. But what about testing the significance of the difference between a new instrument and the old instrument? Please check Edit#2.

Comment: I don't think the sign test is necessarily the best way to approach it, but I don't think your idea will do what you want

Comment: So I guess, it is best to use Wilcoxon test to compare the medians, and use the common sense to reason about the significance.